# Is Voice Control still present in Siri supported devices?

Tags: ipod, siri, voice-dictation

I had an iPod touch two years ago, and it had voice control features for simple things like "next song", or "what time is it".

Is this functionality still present in the current version of iPhone, or has it been replaced by Siri (which does not work off-line)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Voice Control is still available on the iPhone 4S, unless you have **enabled** Siri in the iPhone preferences (listed under the `General` menu).

If Siri is disabled, holding the Home button will still launch the "classic" voice control, which **does** work offline, and also supports a whole lot more languages than Siri currently does.

[image: Disable Siri on an iPhone 4S]

Answer (score -1):

It seams to be available on the iPod Touch. See the [Voice Control feature](http://www.apple.com/ipodtouch/features/voice-control.html).

It was replaced on the iPhone 4S, but not on the older ones . Siri is still just available for the iPhone 4S. It will be available for the iPad 3 with the new IOS 6 but not for any iPod (yet).

Comment: iOS 6 talk is not accepted.

Comment: Siri for iPad 3 with IOS 6 is a confirmed feature, not something that might be there: http://www.apple.com/ios/ios6/siri

Comment: Have a look here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq "pre-release or beta software (We consider versions not available to the public to be in this category)
"

Comment: @MaxRied Technically, if iOS 6 is available to devs, isn't that considered "the public"?

Comment: @Matt This isn't.

Comment: @Matt "Available to devs" is not "available to the general public" - things can still change, even radically (look at the Safari 4 betas, even the generally-available ones).

Comment: @MaxRied I believe that things said on the Apple website, even about prerelease software, are generally fair game for citing, even though they can change.

Comment: @CajunLuke He does not cite it. He claims it. Besides, beta talk is off topic is unwanted.

Comment: @MaxRied He provides a link in a comment; I counted that as a citation. I think beta information - if it comes off public areas of apple.com - is accepted. I cited Mountain Lion's Apple-published specs several times while it was in beta, while making sure to change my answer if Apple changed the data (which they did for Power Nap), and nobody complained, so I believe it's generally acceptable.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, voice control has been replaced by Siri on supported devices.

Comment: It has not been replaced on the iPod. Just on the iPhone 4S and on the iPad 3 (with the new IOS 6).

Comment: I never said it was replaced on the iPod.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I thought the question was whether it was still present on the iPod.

Comment: This is not true. Voice Control is still present on the iPhone 4S, until you **enable** Siri in the preferences.